# Uncaught Invariant Violation: client.watchQuery cannot be called with fetchPolicy set to "standby"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I just clone my project on Ubuntu machine and did `yarn install` and then `yarn` start and this giving me above error. However on my Windows machine it is working fine.

Comment: are you importing `useQuery` from @apollo/react-hooks or apollo-client?

Comment: @GregBrodzik I'm importing it from @apollo/react-hooks

Comment: have you tried replicating the same in windows, deleting node_modules and installing them again, or cloning the repo in a different location and running it there? also, have you made sure to add the lock files to your repo?

Comment: yeah I tried it but no luck.

Comment: I remember getting an error which says subscriptions can't run over non-https endpoint. However not sure if this applies to local. Can you check that? I have a no-code setup that automatically gives me https so my watchQuery always works!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps inside your project folder:

1. `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock`
2. In your `package.json` , `"apollo-client": "~2.6.10"`
3. `yarn install && yarn start`

In our package.json, when we use `^` (in the case here `^2.6.10`), it automatically picks a higher version and it might not be compatible with other packages.
So when this happens, make sure to use the exact version number with `~` as the prefix (in the case here `~2.6.10`).

Comment: "@apollo/client": "~3.4.16",
this answer worked for me. Otherwise, the newer version 3.5 was getting installed and was causing issues.